# How to convert a jsfiddle URL to an iframe embed code using a RegEx?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to convert jsfiddle URLs to proper iframe embeds.

Example URLs:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/user/Lc78dr3y
https://jsfiddle.net/user/Lc78dr3y/
https://jsfiddle.net/user/h1jf34za/11
https://jsfiddle.net/user/h1jf34za/11/
```

And ignore:

```
https://jsfiddle.net
https://jsfiddle.net/
https://jsfiddle.net/user
https://jsfiddle.net/user/
```

What I am using at the moment, see also Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/MEHrKO/1

```
$types = array(
    'jsfiddle' => array(
        array(
            'https{0,1}:\/\/w{0,3}\.*jsfiddle\.net\/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)[^< ]*',
            '<div class="jsfiddle-embed-wrap"><iframe class="iframe-jsfiddle" src="//jsfiddle.net/$1/embedded/result,js,html,css/"></iframe></div>'
        ),
    ),
    // youtube, replit, ...
}

foreach($types as $t  => $ra) {
    // $t is youtube, jsfiddle, replit
    // $ra is array with replacements $ra[0] regex, $ra[1] embed code
    foreach($ra as $r) {
        $text = preg_replace('/<a[^>]+>'.$r[0].'<\/a>/i', $r[1], $text);
        $text = preg_replace('/(?<![\'"=])'.$r[0].'/i', $r[1], $text);
    }
}
```

But it does not work with the code above, I only get the `user` part of the strings:

```
<div class="jsfiddle-embed-wrap"><iframe class="iframe-jsfiddle" src="//jsfiddle.net/user/embedded/result,js,html,css/">
```

Maybe the `$1` is the problem?

Comment: check this https://regex101.com/r/MEHrKO/2 is it what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is getting stuck at `user` because there is no `/` in your character class: `[A-Za-z0-9_-]`.

Unless I misunderstand the question, you only want the fiddle id and the version number (and ignore everything in front of the username).

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6HGOzx/1)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Yomev))

```
$types = array(
    'jsfiddle' => array(
        array(
            'https?:\/\/(?:www)?\.?jsfiddle\.net[\w\/-]*\/([a-z\d]{8}(?:\/\d+)?)\/?',
            '<div class="jsfiddle-embed-wrap"><iframe class="iframe-jsfiddle" src="//jsfiddle.net/$1/embedded/result,js,html,css/"></iframe></div>'
        ),
    ),
    // youtube, replit, ...
);

$text = 'https://jsfiddle.net/user/h1jf34za/11/';

foreach($types as $platformName => $replace) {
    foreach ($replace as [$regex, $embed]) {
        $text = preg_replace(
            [
                '/<a[^>]+>' . $regex . '<\/a>/i',
                '/(?<![\'"=])' . $regex . '/i'
            ],
            $embed,
            $text
        );
    }
}
echo $text;
```

Output:

```
<div class="jsfiddle-embed-wrap"><iframe class="iframe-jsfiddle" src="//jsfiddle.net/h1jf34za/11/embedded/result,js,html,css/"></iframe></div>
```

Your patterns already have `i` modifiers, so `[A-Z]` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As per your examples you could use

```
\Qhttps://jsfiddle.net/user/\E\S+
```

This matches all of your desired urls while ignoring the others, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/MEHrKO/3).